# Windows form setting datetimepicker to 31st march of every year

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Right now the code display current date in the date time picker.
How do I display 31st March in 2017 and once it is 2018, it will display 31st March 2018 and so on and so forth as the year progress

Anyone help would be greatly appreciated
[image]

Comment: I would recommend looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) and seeing which property is used to set the date.

Answer (score 1):

```
int currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;
DateTime desiredDate = new DateTime(currentYear, 3, 31);
```

Additional info: apparently Asker doesn't know class [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

You asked:

> How do I display 31st March in 2017 and once it is 2018, it will
>   display 31st March 2018 and so on and so forth as the year progress

This is a difficult way to say that you want  31 march of the current year (= the year of Today)

- DateTime.Today fetches the date of Today (surprise, surprise!)
- Property Year contains the Year of Today

On 15th November 2017, Year was 2017

- new DateTime(currentYear, 3, 31) will make the date of 31st March of the current year (which in my example was 2017

Surely you did read the documentation of the DateTime structure, didn't you?

Comment: Can you explain a bit your snippet?